# Repeat system() command in C++?

Tags: c++, cmd, ping

What is the easiest way to repeat a simple system command on multiple CMD's in C++?  For instance, how could I repeat this code on multiple terminal windows from my C++ code?

`system( ("ping "+ ip +" -t -l 32").c_str() );`

Comment: `std::async` may be helpful to you. Documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: Is `std::system` thread-safe? I feel like the since the behavior of `std::system` is essentially unspecified, any meaningful suggestion would need to specify the target platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a networking perspective, I don't think that pinging a single system from multiple terminals will be as effective as pinging that system from multiple remote systems.

Anyways, in regards to the easiest way to ping a system from multiple processes... just use the shell directly. Something like:

```
target=s4
for remotehost in s1 s2 s3; do (ssh -n $remotehost ping $target -t -l 32 & ) ; done
```

The "remotehost" doesn't have to really be a remote host either. You can just use "localhost" multiple times (instead of multiple names of remote hosts).

Alternatively if you really want to use C++ from a single host:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string ip = "foo";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::system(("ping " + ip + " -t -l 32 & ").c_str());
    }
}
```

Note the usage of the ampersand (&) character in the input string to the `system` function. That instructs the shell to run the given task in the background. That way `system` returns immediately and the ping command basically runs at the same time as the two other instances of the command.

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: This only opens a single command prompt

Comment: @CedricStrobe It opens multiple command prompts, but likely only one at a time.

Comment: Is there a way to have them running at the same time?

Comment: Given the usage of the ampersand (&) character, I'd expect the shell to run the given job in the background such that `system` returns immediately. This way it's more like a fork and exec of the pings and they run at the same time.

Comment: @CedricStrobe I've also updated my answer to help call attention to the background task invoking operator - the ampersand.